# How can I set focus to explorer in C# WindowsApiCodepack, when used in WPF via WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, explorer, setfocus, windowsformshost

i´m writing a small C# Wpf application and I integrated the ExplorerBrowser of the WindowsApiCodepack.
This is working really nice.
The only problem I have and where I haven´t found a solution so far is:
How can I programatically set the focus (keyboard focus) to the ExplorerBrowser control, so that I can select a folder without clicking on it with the mouse before?

Does someone have exerience with the control?

Additional Note:
What I found out so far is, that focus problems are a common problem for winform controls, which are inserted into a wpf window via the WindowsFormsHost class.
But i haven´t found a good workaround so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue about the WindowsApiCodepack, but I think u just have to call the ".Focus()" function of the control.

Comment: That was the first I looked for, but it doesn´t give me keyboard focus or even control focus.

I´m not sure if it has something to do with the fact that the explorer wpf control is a wrapper for the WinForms explorer control.
But i tried to give focus to the wpf control as well as on the inner winforms control.